# How to insert new document to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema created now i want to save new document to collection but its not happening with below code, I am new to mongodb any help will be appreciated.

routes.js

```
var Diagram = require('./diagram');
router.post('/saveNewDiagram',function(req,res){
   Diagram.save(req.body);
});
```

diagram.js

```
var diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Diagram = {

    update: function(req, res) {
        diagram.update({
            _id: req._id
        }, {
            $set: {
                'string': req.string
            }
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                console.log("successfully updated document");
            }
        });


    },
    save: function(req, res) {
        var newDiagram = new diagram();
        newDiagram.save(req.body);
    }
}
module.exports = Diagram;
```

model.js

```
var DiagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});
 module.exports=mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);
```

Comment: what is your /diagram.model js file?

Comment: added to question

Comment: Dude you call the method "Diagram.save(req.body);" with req.body parameter but in your function definition you get the whole req object and save req.body

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong in save function, you `save` function should be like

```
save: function(req, res) {
    var newDiagram = new diagram(req.body);
    newDiagram.save();
}
```

and make sure `req.body` only have `string` and/or `text` fields. You may like to add following check

```
save: function(req, res) {
    var diagramData = {
        string: req.body.string,
        text: req.body.text
    }
    var newDiagram = new diagram(diagramData);
    newDiagram.save();
}
```